# SSD partition for a UI development workstation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, google-chrome, ssd

I am dual booting my PC with a 512GB SSD and I'll be using installing the latest LTS Ubuntu(22) and be using it for UI development. This means that I'll have the following running:

- Around 60 chrome tabs open at any time.
- Around 30 Opera tabs
- Around 30 Firefox tabs A couple of Node servers
- Mongo cache + server instance
- Two or three UI servers (React or such)
- And maybe a backend server of some sort at extremes.
- Three or four Vscode instances
- A SQL DB server and such.

I don't know how much space I should reserve on the partition for UBUNTU, and out of that how much I can fill and how much of the partition I should leave empty. I am leaning towards 50-60 GB from all the articles, but I'm not sure if that will be enough. All the other questions I found were really old and for considerably different scenarios than mine.

Side Note: To support all this I have the latest i5 processor, 16GB of RAM, and a large extra monitor connected to the RTX3060 graphics card. In short, I believe the machine should be able to take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development machines tend to require extra disk space. For what you are trying to do allocating a 256GB partition for Ubuntu would be nice. Don't waste disk space by creating extra partitions that you don't need. I don't think you will run out of disk space on this computer any time soon, but if you do you can buy a larger SSD and reinstall Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Are there some calculations or considerations for 256GB, or is it what you have used without issue? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is what I am using right now. I have two 256GB SSDs in my workstation. One is for Ubuntu 22.04. I have enabled Ubuntu Pro on this OS so it is supported until 2032. I will use my Ubuntu 22.04 for running legacy software. Starting with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS I will dual boot on my workstation and use the other SSD for the latest Ubuntu LTS release. In addition to these two SSDs I have a large capacity drive that I use for data storage.